# yield in nested generator function

Tags: python

What should I do to make it work?

```
def my_yield(l):
    try:
        x = open(l[0], 'r')
        y = open(l[1], 'w')
        yield x, y
    finally:
        x.close()
        y.close()




def my_wrapper(list):
    for l in list:
        return my_yield(l)   #<<< what should I put here??


def main():
    list = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
    for key, value in my_wrapper(list):
        print key, value
main()
```

In the original function the `my_wrapper` does a bit more.

The logical solution would be to yield in `my_wrapper` and return in `my_yield` but in this case the files would be closed by the time they reach the loop in main.

Comment: The good start would be to replace `'w]` with `'w'`

Comment: why do you need a wrapper around the generator ?

Comment: What is the bigger picture here - what are you trying to achieve, and why have you concluded that `yield`ing two open files through a wrapper function is the way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yield` in both the wrapper and the wrapped functions. So

```
def my_yield(l):
    try:
        x = open(l[0], 'r')
        y = open(l[1], 'w')
        yield x, y
    finally:
        x.close()
        y.close()

def my_wrapper(the_list):
    for l in the_list:
        yield my_yield(l)
```

This works just fine in many situations. For example, here's code that returns each pair of adjacent items in a list:

```
def create_list():
    for i in range(5):
        yield i

def pair_list():
    generator = create_list()
    first = next(generator)
    for second in generator:
        yield first, second
        first = second
```

However, using `yield` in your `my_yield` leaves you open to a very significant problem - the `yield` statement causes the code to leave control of the `my_yield` function, only to return at the next iteration of the `for` loop or call to `next`. This means the files will only be closed if there is not an exception.

To illustrate:

```
for x, y in my_yield(('1', '2'))
    raise Exception('BORKED!')
```

This results in `x` and `y` being opened, but never being closed.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see the need for using a wrapper, arond the generator, you can have the generator yield the tuple and use that in the loop. Another thing, using list as a variable name is not recommended since there is a container named `list`.

```
def gen(mylist):
    for elem in mylist:
        yield (elem[0], elem[1])

def main():
    mylist = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
    for key, value in gen(mylist):
        with open(key, 'r') as keyfile:
            with open(value, 'w') as valuefile:
                #do whatever with keyfile and valuefile

main()
```